# Automatically change background image in swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, background

How would I automatically change the background image using a timer i.e. after 5 seconds one background image transitions to another? How do you do this in Swift?

Answer (score 4):

```
 NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: "ChangeImage", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

and in Action change Image like

```
 func ChangeImage()
{
    NSLog("asdasd");
    imgView.image = UIImage(named: "img.png");
}
```